# Is there any way to subtract one Object property value from another in multiple lists?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have several lists. Monthly lists. The objects contained in them have a value. The goal is to subtract the value of the first monthobject from the value of the second monthobject. 
and save the new value

next step is to subtract the original value of the second month from the third month value. and safe the new third month value. the original value of the third month is to subtract from the fourth one etc. etc.

Now, what i have done among other variants, but I think that's the closest I get.

**This is one of my attempts**:

```
    //creates multiple ArrayLists in List, based on numbers of monthList
       for (int i = 0; i < monthList.size(); i++) {
           monthyList.add(new ArrayList<>());
       }

    List<Objecty> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < monthyList.size(); i++) {
        List<Object> firstMonthList = monthyList.get(i);
        List<Object> nextMonthList = monthyList.get(i + 1);

        List<Object> copyOfNextList = List.copyOf(nextMonthList);

        for (int j = 0; j < firstMonthList.size(); j++) {
            Object firstMonthObject = firstMonthList.get(j);
            for (int k = 0; k < copyOfNextList.size(); k++) {
                Object nextMonthObject = copyOfNextList.get(k);
                if (nextMonthObject.getAccountNumber() == firstMonthObject.getAccountNumber()) {

                     nextMonthObject.setAmount(subtractAmount(firstMonthObject.getAmount(),nextMonthObject.getAmount()));
                    finalList.add(nextMonthObject);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    finalList.add....

}
```

So unfortunately I cannot get any further... does it have any advantages to use LinkedList for this case?

I hope the problem is understandably.

Can you help me improve the code?  Or are there better approaches to solve this problem?

Comment: An example input and the expected output in the same form as your actual data, so lists instead of ints, would add to clarity.

Comment: hope it's better understandable

Comment: Your question, intention and problem are all unclear. Is it that you want to create deltas from a series of values? If so, there seems to be a lot of code. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and remove as much as you can from your question, and make it as narrow as you can. Also, sample input data (the raw data, not lists of lists, which is an implementation choice, possibly a poor one) and desired output data.

Comment: @Bohemian edit the question